# Calling AWS API within Phonegap framework

Tags: cordova

I have just picked up Phonegap and found it amazing.
I am now trying to write an app using phoneapp, primarily service Android devices, and will be interacting some of the backend hosted on AWS.
I want to be able to make API calls to AWS services like S3 and DynamoDB so as to build some native storage function into my app, but I am not sure how...as I do not need to import the android SDK library of AWS in Phonegap.

I searched both stackoverflow and AWS forum but didn't get much help from there.  Wondering if anyone can share some experience.

regards.
CY

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap apps are web apps. You should access your api through rest calls using your favourite frontend framework or just javascript. Have a look at http://angularjs.org/ and http://devgirl.org/2013/06/10/quick-start-guide-phonegap-and-angularjs/

Comment: Via the devgirl link, seems like there is a way to build android plugin for Phonegap, maybe I should embed android API for AWS into the plugin?